# How to clone to an existing directory with SmartGit?

Tags: git, smartgit

I have an existing repository on BitBucket, and am cloning it locally using SmartGit 3 on Windows 7 (x64). I have a folder, let's say `C:/FolderA/FolderB` that I want to place it in. (So that `readme.txt` becomes `C:/FolderA/FolderB/readme.txt`.)

However, when I clone the repository, and set the Path to `C:/FolderA/FolderB`, it creates `readme.txt` in `C:/FolderA/FolderB/repository-name/readme.txt`. How can I prevent this?

If there is no way to do this with SmartGit, how can I achieve it from the Git command line?

NB: Google had nothing to say on this, either... [[1]](https://www.google.com/search?q=smartgit+clone+to+existing+folder) [[2]](https://www.google.com/search?q=smartgit+force+directory+name) [[3]](https://www.google.com/search?q=smartgit+clone+to+custom+folder) etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
git clone <git-url> [target-dir]
```

If you do not specify target dir, it will by default create new directory named after repo name (and this is what you are seeing).

You can always rename your target dir or move it around as you wish (one level up for example) - git does not really care, as long as `.git` sub-dir is intact.

Comment: That last bit was the nail in the coffin; just moved the directory up and now all is well (with a bit of tweaking in SmartGit). Thank you!

Comment: 4 years later, so probably no hope of getting an answer, but I'd like to know how Eric tweaked SmartGit to get it to move the local repo.

Comment: @Rebeccah: answer still as valid as it was 4 years ago: move or rename your directory around as you wish, that's all it takes'

Comment: Well, no, but I just figured it out.  AFTER moving the directory around, I have to remove the repo in SmartGit and then add it back with the new local location.

Comment: @Rebeccah: perhaps SmartGit is not so smart, after all :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, too (at least with respect to this particular task).  I had similar trouble figuring out how to track a different remote repo for purpose of merging two repos -- this "add" concept is for some reason kind of slow to sink in.  :-)